# PHP and Wordpress - Place content in correct column

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a FAQ page. Consisiting of questions. The order of the questions does not matter. What matters is the layout. Its a three column layout.

When you only have 3 questions, the layout is correct. It looks like this.

[question Z] [question A] [question O]

The problem: 
When you have 4 questions the layout looks like this.

[question Z] [question A]
[question X] [question O]

It should look like this.

[question Z] [question A] [question O]
[question X]

Its a 3 column layout.
I would like the questions to fill out the fist row. Than start with the second.

I need to do this, without chaning the Bootstrap grid.

The gird was set up in such a way, that when the user clicks read more on a question, only the column expand and not the row.

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php 
        $counter=0;
        $total_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
        $posts_per_column = ceil($total_posts / 3);
    ?>


<section class="faq content">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container-wrapper-faq">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
            <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); $counter++; ?>                 
          <div class="faq-all">
            <div class="faq-item">
              <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
              <article>
                <div class="faq-intro">
                   <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="faq-info">
                   <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>   
                <div class="faq-link">
                  <a href="#" class="read-more">LES HELE SVARET</a>
                  <a href="#" class="read-less">LES MINDRE</a>
              </div>
             </article>
            </div>
          </div> 
            <!-- Close and open div if the "counter" divided by the "posts per column" of columns you want equals zero -->
            <?php if($counter % $posts_per_column == 0) echo '</div></div><div class="col-lg-4"><div class="col-lg-12">'; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: outputted html & applied css?

Comment: try to remove the `<div class="col-lg-12">` div, it's unnecessary

Comment: I need it to expand the column instead of the row when the user clicks on read more. Without it, the row would take on the size of the expand question. And the other question in the same row would have alot of white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am sure there is a cleaner way to pull this off but its early and my brain is not functioning at 100%. This should fix your problem. Basically if the total posts = 4,7,10,13... what we had before would always trim it so that it never reached the 3rd column. I added some code that checks to see if it is one of these special cases I just did some basic math and subtracted the total posts by one, then divided that by three, if it is a round number I know its a special case. So I change the posts per column to be one less, then in the loop we check if its the first post and we don't increment the counter.

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
  $counter=0;
  $columns=3;
  $total_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
  $posts_per_column = ceil($total_posts / 3);
  $posts_per_column_test_value = ($total_posts - 1) / $columns;
  $is_special_case = false;
    if($total_posts != 1 && (intval($posts_per_column_test_value) == $posts_per_column_test_value)){
        $is_special_case = true;
        $posts_per_column = $posts_per_column - 1;
    }
?>
<section class="faq content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container-wrapper-faq">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
                  if($is_special_case && $wp_query->current_post == 0){
                            // do nothing so we get an extra post in the first column
                            } else { 
                                $counter++
                            }: ?>                 
                  <div class="faq-all">
                    <div class="faq-item">
                      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                      <article>
                        <div class="faq-intro">
                           <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="faq-info">
                           <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>   
                        <div class="faq-link">
                          <a href="#" class="read-more">LES HELE SVARET</a>
                          <a href="#" class="read-less">LES MINDRE</a>
                      </div>
                     </article>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
            <?php
                // Close and open div if the "counter" divided by the "posts per column" of columns you want equals zero
                if($counter % $posts_per_column == 0) echo '</div></div><div class="col-lg-4"><div class="col-lg-12">';
            ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```